# Why does Muzan Kibutsuji Crossdress?

Tags: demon-slayer

At the end of season 1 of Demon Slayer you can see Muzan Kibutsuji the demon who looks like Michael Jackson dressed in a yukata of some sort wearing makeup and lipstick.

Has anyone who read the manga know about anything related to this topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is one of his ability called **[Shapeshifting](https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Muzan_Kibutsuji)**

Muzan can control his body's shape and even his presence, making him able to transform into someone completely different, without even those with extrasensory perception noticing, though he cannot fool Tanjiro Kamado's sense of scent. This shapeshifting allows him to become a child, and adult, **a woman**, or even to become a pillar of flesh, eyes, or mouths to eat others, or a cocoon of flesh to dilate and adapt to poisons.